# phpunit db extension fails on createMySQLXMLDataSet

Tags: php, xml, utf-8, phpunit

I'm trying to load a dataset created by `mysqldump --xml`. Using:

```
public function getDataSet()
{
    return $this->createMySQLXMLDataSet('/path/file.xml');
}
```

When I run the test, I get:

```
RuntimeException: PCDATA invalid Char value 1
PCDATA invalid Char value 1
PCDATA invalid Char value 1
PCDATA invalid Char value 1
PCDATA invalid Char value 1
PCDATA invalid Char value 1
PCDATA invalid Char value 1
```

It appears to be having issues with a column of type `bit(1)`. Is there some way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like mysqldump creates invalid XML for `bit` columns. You have to specify the `--hex-blob` option.

Comment: Yes, the error message you got sounds like a control character in the lower range like NUL or SOH for the bit.